# Opportunity Page Auto Refresh Issue

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have implemented a custom lightning component with recordEditForm and updating opp stagename which accidentally refreshing the page but when i remove stagename input field from the form its working fine and not refreshing the page.

**please help this is urgent.**

Thanks,

Component Code -

```
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Opportunity"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Opportunity"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>

{!v.saved}

<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
  recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
  fields="Name"
  />

<!-- Display a lightning card with details about the record -->
<div class="Record Details"> 
<lightning:card iconName="standard:opportunity" title="{!v.simpleRecord.Name}" >
    <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
        <p class="slds-text-heading--small">
            <lightning:formattedText title="Billing City" value="{!v.simpleRecord.Name}" /></p>
        <p class="slds-text-heading--small">
            <lightning:formattedText title="Billing State" value="{!v.simpleRecord.StageName}" /></p>
    </div>
</lightning:card>
</div>

<!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors, if any -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordError))}">
    <div class="recordError">
        {!v.recordError}</div>
</aura:if>

<aura:if isTrue="{!!v.saved}">
    <lightning:recordEditForm
        aura:id="submitform"
        onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
        onsuccess="{!c.handleSaveStage}"
        recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        objectApiName="Opportunity">
        <!-- the messages component is for error messages -->
        <lightning:messages />

        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
            <lightning:button disabled="{!v.disabled}" variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" />
        </div>

        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="StageName" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Annuity_Project__c" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Deal_Administrator__c" />

    </lightning:recordEditForm>
    <aura:set attribute="else">            
        <p>Saved!!</p>
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.Spinner}">
    <div aura:id="spinnerId" class="slds-spinner_container">
        <div class="slds-spinner--brand  slds-spinner slds-spinner--large slds-is-relative" role="alert">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

Controller -

```
handleSubmit : function(component, event, helper){
     event.preventDefault();
     component.find("submitform").submit();
     //helper.showSpinner(component, event, helper);
},
```

[image]

Comment: Do share the relevant code as well.

Comment: Please see code updated above and also this work properly when i use this in separate app but when i embed this component on Opportunity record page and submit the form it refresh and when i comment this LOC (stagename) it work properly.

Comment: Try force: refreshView in the success callback.

Comment: Is whole page  refreshing  or only a view refreshing?

Comment: not the whole browser but content view page and it gets blank. Please see the screenshot.

Comment: Hey Guys, Just thanks to all for your suggestions.

I got the root cause of the issue and that was, in the background some old code was executing and changing recordtype which also change the page layout. Now once i inactive that workflow rule its working nice.

Answer (score 0):

Just thanks to all for your suggestions. I got the root cause of the issue and that was, in the background some old code was executing and changing recordtype which also change the page layout. Now once i inactive that workflow rule its working nice.